# How to assign a string value to buttons on click event using GTM custom javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I’ve got a website with three buttons with the same button text, class (.action-button) etc. The click URL:s are different, but they will change on a regular basis so I think I’ll have to target them using CSS selector. I would like to be able to identify, and give each of these buttons a string as value if clicked. The purpose is to send the value to GA via a UA event tag, but I don’t want to hardcode it.

I’m not quite sure how to approach this (I’m a js beginner). I’ve written a script that I put in a custom javascript variable. Unfortunately, it isn’t working. When I try it out in the debug mode the variable gets ’undefined’ as both return type and value. Does anyone know what’s wrong with my script? Or if I could achieve the same result in a different, simpler way?

I have set up regular click triggers for each of the buttons using .spotlight-coll-one-big-two-small-img-below .spotlight:nth-child(1, 2 or 3) .action-button, and those work just fine.

Using document.querySelectorAll('.spotlight-coll-one-big-two-small-img-below .action-button') gives me a NodeList with the three buttons I want to target.

```
function() {
var theSpotlight = document.querySelectorAll('.spotlight-coll-one-big-two-small-img-below .action-button');
if (theSpotlight.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < theSpotlight.length; i++) {
        theSpotlight[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (theSpotlight[i] = 0) {
                return 'Spotlight 1'
            } else if (theSpotlight[i] = 1) {
                return 'Spotlight 2'
            } else if (theSpotlight[i] = 2) {
                return 'Spotlight 3'
            } else {
                return 'n/a'
            }
        })
    }
   }
 }
```

PS. I cannot access the code at this point.

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

**Add click handler JavaScript to page**

This has to be added on your website, and not as a custom JS variable in GTM

```
function() {
var theSpotlight = document.querySelectorAll('.spotlight-coll-one-big-two-small-img-below .action-button');
var spotLightLabels = ['Spotlight 1', 'Spotlight 2', 'Spotlight 3'];
if (theSpotlight.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < theSpotlight.length; i++) {
        theSpotlight[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            window.dataLayer.push({'spotlightLabel': spotlightLabels[i]});
        });
    }
   }
 }
```

**In GTM**

- Create a dataLayer variable that reads the value of `spotlightLabel`
- Use that dataLayer variable wherever you need the text label of the last spotlight link clicked

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would there be a reasonable workaround to this if I cannot add code to the website right now?

Comment: You can try adding the above as a custom HTML tag in GTM, and set the tag firing priority to fire as early as possible